# About SenInvoice method from telegram bot api

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

so i want to use this sendinvoice command [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendinvoice)

But i kinda confused about what start _parameter means and how to use array of labeled price .

can you give me some example especially on how u use / declare array of labeledprice ?

Answer (score 0):

Start parameter is just unique string to use deep linking (when user open bot, bot pass to user his invoice)

according [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#labeledprice)

This is array with price and other partitions. Tax for example.